# project .cs files contain using Microsoft.SharePoint;

Tags: .net, sharepoint

I am trying to migrate a solution that was used in SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013.  I tested the project in 2010 and it functions there.  It doesn't work in 2013.  I found a number of errors related to .net 3.5 vs. .net 4.5.  How do I change the cs files to accept use in .net 4.5?

Comment: are you able to open the solution/project file in VS 2013? if yes then change the target framework to 4.5

Comment: Add errors from Migration tools...I strongly doubt that the error in .NET, otherwise would not have come up with Rendering template